# Why do Chromebooks no longer allow VPN connections in Guest Mode?

Tags: vpn, chrome

This is reproducible in stable, beta, and developer channels. It is also ticketed on their website:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=308811

Any ideas as to why VPN connections no longer appear to work in Guest Mode?

Answer (score 2):

On first look I would think this is an accident or that something was unintentionally changed which broke this for certain VPN clients. VPN client software is notoriously fragile and depending on the client and/or provider one may work flawlessly while another doesn't.

Searching regarding this turned up several forum posts such as this one, titled: [I can't get L2TP/IPSec + PSK VPN working with Samsung Chromebook](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/eGS1KPOfUJY). Most of the results would seem to indicate instability in some component of Chromebook that is causing the breakage.

Other threads:

- [Does ANYONE have a working VPN from their chromebook(s) to a corporate (enterprise) network?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/chromebook-central/tVo9Xjuf-jE/NwCanAgku90J)
- [google search: chromebook no longer allows vpn](https://www.google.com/search?q=chromebook%20no%20longer%20allows%20vpn&oq=chromebook%20no%20longer%20allows%20vpn&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j65l3j0.4554j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Very good references. However, connecting while logged in works great, but when logged in as a guest it does not work. I'm sure they are working on it.